# What is the correct technical term for this generalization of an integer partition?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, terminology, integer-partitions

Given a vector $v$ with non-negative integer coordinates, is there a technical term for an unordered tuple of vectors $(v_1,\dots, v_k)$ with non-negative integer coordinates such that

$v_1+\dots+v_k = v$?

I would have liked to have called it a Vector Partition of $v$, but that term seems to be used for a decomposition a vector as a linear combination with non-negative integral coefficients of a fixed set of vectors.

An authoritative reference for the usage would also be welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "unordered tuple"?

Comment: I mean that the order in which the summands $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are taken does not matter, but the number of times each $v_i$ occurs does matter (this is akin to integer partitions).

Comment: Actually, I believe that an integer partition is exactly what you want. If the order does not matter, then you can as well put them in a descending order. If the order would matter, I would consider [multiindices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation).

Comment: How is your definition different from "a decomposition a vector as a linear combination with non-negative integral coefficients of any nonzero vectors with non-negative integral entries"? (I take it you forbid a zero vector among the $v_i$, since that would cause infitely many possibilities. Or do you fix the values of $k$ beforehand?) In other words, isn't this a special case of the Vector Partition problem with a specific infinite fixed set of vectors?

Comment: @Marc Yes, indeed, it is a special case. I want to know if this special case (where all non-zero integer vectors are allowed) has a special name. Do I gather correctly from your comment that one cannot do better than "Vector Partition"?

Comment: @Jesko Integer partitions are integers that add up to a given integer. I am looking at integer vectors that add up to a given integer vector.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally misread. How stupid, I'm sorry.

Comment: @AmritanshuPrasad: Yes you may infer that I do not know of a better term. That is not saying much though, I've never much studied this kind of problems.

Comment: @Jesko No worries; I do it all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

The closest term in the literature, I think, is *multiway number partitioning*. A recent work is out [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.02710.pdf). Note that the work even discusses about amore general problem- of partition the list so that the sum is as close as possible.